# Android Studio Problem: Caches have to be invalidated after every start

Tags: java, android, android-studio, androidx

I have a really strange problem. I have been using multiple Java classes with AndroidX for more than 1 year without any problems. Now all of a sudden, I get many error of the form:

```
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout; -- > Cannot resolve symbol 'constraintlayout'
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment; -- > Cannot resolve symbol 'app'
```

Here is a screenshot from Android Studio
[image]

And here is the whole code:

```
package com.example.game;



import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.game.databinding.FragmentTestBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FR_Test extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


    /*
    Game variables
     */

    public static final int DELAY_IN_MILLIS = 100;
    ArrayList<View_Game_Event_Rectangle> arrayList_GameEventRectangles;
    private int currentTimeSlot;
    private boolean gameIsRunning;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int timeslotsEventElementUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 = (int)(5.0 * (1000.0/DELAY_IN_MILLIS));
    private int numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 = 5000;

    //Fix parameters of the UI elements
    private float horizontalPercentageOfScoreRectangle_End = 0.491f;
    private float horizontalPercentageOfScoreRectangle_Start = 0.567f;
    private float verticalBiasOfEventElementToBeInTheLine = 0.049f;
    private float percentageHeightOfEventElement = 0.071f;


    int widthDisplay;
    int heightDisplay;
    int helpCounterRun =0;
    int helpCounterUpdateScreen =0;
    int helpCounterCountDownTime =0;

    private FragmentTestBinding binding;
    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    ConstraintSet constraintSet ;

    //Variables for the single view event
    View_Game_Event_Rectangle[] viewEvent;

    private boolean fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = false;
    private CountDownTimer cdt;
    private  final long DURATION = 900000L;
    private  final long DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER = 100;

    private int numberOfTimeSlotsUntilTheEndOfScreen = (int)(numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 * 2/(DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER));
    private int currentLevel;
    public FR_Test() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        arrayList_GameEventRectangles = new ArrayList<View_Game_Event_Rectangle>();
        currentLevel = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getWindowManager();
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        widthDisplay = size.x;
        heightDisplay = size.y;
        container.getContext();
        constraintLayout= binding.constraintLayout;
        fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = true;
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        constraintLayout = binding.constraintLayout;
        constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        startGame();
        return binding.getRoot();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }


    public void startGame () {
        gameIsRunning = true;
        Log.e("LogTag_El", "-------Start Game------" );

        //Create rectangle-element that should be animated from the right to the left on the screen
        arrayList_GameEventRectangles.add(new View_Game_Event_Rectangle(getActivity(), "Bulb Rectangle", 100, 20));
        countDownTime();
    }


    private void updateScreen() {

        for (int currentElement =0; currentElement <arrayList_GameEventRectangles.size(); currentElement++) {

            //Create view and set
            if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot() - 50) {

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setActive(true);


                //Set the parameters and the backgrund of the view element
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));

                if(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getEventType().equals("Bulb Rectangle")) {
                    arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.game_event_rectangle_bulb_1).mutate());
                }

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setId(View.generateViewId());

                //Make the view invisible (before it's appearence time)
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getBackground().setAlpha(0);

                // Set the ConstraintLayout programatically for the view
                constraintLayout.addView(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement));
                constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
                constraintSet.constrainPercentHeight(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), percentageHeightOfEventElement);

                float widthConstrainPercentage_element1 = (float)(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getDuration() / 100.0);
                float duration = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getDuration();

                constraintSet.constrainPercentWidth(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), widthConstrainPercentage_element1);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);

                float horizontalBias = 1.0f ;
                constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), horizontalBias);
                constraintSet.setVerticalBias(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), verticalBiasOfEventElementToBeInTheLine);
                constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);

            }


            //Shift the view to the right border of the display
            if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot() - 40) {
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setTranslationX(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getWidth());
            }


            //Animate view element
            if (currentTimeSlot ==arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot()) {
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                long durationForTheAnimation = (long)(numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 * 1);

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).animate().setDuration(durationForTheAnimation).translationX(widthDisplay*(-1)).start();

            }
            helpCounterUpdateScreen++;
            checkPositionsOfActiveElements();

        }

    }

    private void countDownTime(){

        cdt = new CountDownTimer(DURATION, DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER) {
            boolean delay = true;
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(delay) {
                    delay = false;
                } else {

                    helpCounterCountDownTime++;
                    currentTimeSlot++;

                    updateScreen();
                    delay = true;
                }
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                updateScreen();
            }
        }.start();

    }

    public void checkPositionsOfActiveElements () {
        for (int currentElement =0; currentElement <arrayList_GameEventRectangles.size(); currentElement++) {
            //Check if the view is still running
            if (arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).isActive() == true && currentElement==0) {
                Log.e("LogTag_FGa_CP", "currentTimeSlot: " + currentTimeSlot);
                Log.e("LogTag_FGa_CP", "currentElement.getX(): " + arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getX());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        // Reset your variable to false
        fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = false;

        // And clean up any postDelayed callbacks that are waiting to fire
        cdt.cancel();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
}
```

So there is a problem with importing the elements from AndroidX as you can see that the imports are grey. However, the very strange aspect is, that the app can be build, compiled and started without any problems in the Android Studio Emulator (as it had been the case during the last months). Can you tell me, why I get these error messages, and why the app still starts? I have to invalidate the caches after each start of Android Studio. This problem happens always with the classes of AndroidX but sometimes also with other classes.

Comment: Try File > Invalidate Caches.

Comment: @WaisKamal: Thanks Wais for your comment. It helped but unforunatley this problem occurs quite often. So I have to invalidate the caches every day. Do you know why this is happening and how to tackle this issue

Comment: I am not sure what can be done because I never encountered something like this before. Are you on the latest version of Android Studio?

Comment: @WaisKamal: Yes, I use the latest version of Android Studio Electric Eel. Maybe this is the problem, because before that version it was working properly. Maybe there is even a bug in Electric Eel because I found it to be very unstable.

Comment: @WaisKamal: Thanks Wais for your comment. Any comment on my last comment? I still get this problem every time I start Android Studio Electric Eel. The striking aspect is that the errors always refer to the AndroidX libraries. So there might be something wrong with them. Do you have any idea as to why this is happening? I'll appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: Sorry for showing up late, I was so busy last week. When you start Android Studio, do you see a loading bar at the bottom telling that Android Studio is indexing your files?

Comment: @WaisKamal: Thanks Wais for your comment. Yes, Android Studio was indexing my files all the time. I will now delete Android Studio and reinstall it. Maybe something was broken with the installation

Comment: If the issue persists after reinstalling, I recommend you [file a bug report](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs).

Comment: @WaisKamal: I am using Android Studio now on an other notebook and the problem still persists. I always have to invalidate the cache after every start of android studio, otherwise the problem occurs with the AndroidX elements.

Comment: @WaisKamal: I still have that problem even on a new computer. Any further comments from you are highly appreciated